# Open only one instance of a text file

Tags: vba

In VBA, I have a function that opens a text file.  This allows me to place a button on a form and have it show a file when clicked.

The function works fine, however the aforementioned button is clicked multiple times, it will open the same document over and over, rather than just the once.

How can I make it so that a file is only opened once?

```
Sub OpenTextFile(ByVal filePath As String)

    If Len(Dir(filePath)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Ensure that the file to open actaully exists

    Dim txtFile As Variant
    txtFile = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & filePath, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it reasonable in your workflow to `buttonName.Enabled = False` after the file is opened so the user does not click it again?

Comment: I see where you are going, but what if the user closes the file and then wants to open it again later?

Comment: Maybe not ideal, you could out a button "I have closed the file" the enables the button again. `buttonName.Enabled = True`  If you know that it will always be open in notepad.exe you could verify that notepad is not running before you enable it.  But then they couldn't use notepad for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if a Shell ID has previously been assigned to the Workbooks `.CustomDocumentProperties` property. If it has, then we need to check if that Shell ID instance is still open. We can do that by using the Shell ID and passing it into the `WHERE` clause of a query against `Win32_Process`.

If there is no Shell ID assigned to the property, we can go straight to opening the text file. Once we open the text file, we update the `.CustomDocumentProperties` Property with the new text file Shell ID.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenTextFile()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim txtFile As Long
    Dim txtOpenCount As Integer

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wmiService As Object, winQry As Object

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    txtFile = CLng(wb.CustomDocumentProperties("txtFileNum"))

    If Err.Number = 0 Then '' If CustomDocumentProperty returned _
                              without an error then use this to close txt file.

        Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                                 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                                 & ".\root\cimv2")
        Set winQry = wmiService.ExecQuery _
                     ("SELECT * from Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " & txtFile)

        txtOpenCount = winQry.Count

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    If txtOpenCount = 0 Then '' If the txtFile is not found, then open.

        filePath = "F:\test.txt"

        If txtFile > 0 Then
            wb.CustomDocumentProperties("txtFileNum").Delete
        End If

        txtFile = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & filePath, vbNormalFocus)

        '' Update CustomDocumentProperty with the new txtFile number.
        wb.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="txtFileNum", _
                                        Value:=txtFile, _
                                        LinkToContent:=False, _
                                        Type:=msoPropertyTypeString

    End If

End Sub
```

If you are in Access, you can take advantage of the `.CreateProperty` method, and then the `.Properties.Append` method. You have to pass the property created from `.CreateProperty` into the `.Properties.Append` method. Updated code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenTextFile()

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim txtFile As Long, oTxt As Object
    Dim txtOpenCount As Integer

    Dim db As Database
    Dim wmiService As Object, winQry As Object

    Set db = CurrentDb

    On Error Resume Next
    txtFile = db.Properties("txtFileNum").Value

    If Err.Number = 0 Then '' If CustomDocumentProperty returned _
                              without an error then use this to close txt file.

        Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                                 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                                 & ".\root\cimv2")
        Set winQry = wmiService.ExecQuery _
                     ("SELECT * from Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " & txtFile)

        txtOpenCount = winQry.Count

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    If txtOpenCount = 0 Then '' If the txtFile is not found, then open.

        filePath = "F:\test.txt"

        If txtFile > 0 Then
            db.Properties.Delete "txtFileNum"
        End If

        txtFile = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & filePath, vbNormalFocus)

        '' Update db Properties with the new txtFile number.
        Set oTxt = db.CreateProperty("txtFileNum", dbLong, txtFile, False)
        db.Properties.Append oTxt


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm using Access and it appears that the `CustomDocumentProperties` method is unfortunately not available.  There is a `Properties` method available, but it appears that I cannot use this.  I changed `Dim wb As Workbook` to `Dim DB As DAO.Database`, `ThisWorkbook` to `CurrentDb` and all references to `wb` to `DB`.

Comment: Please see the updated code: you have to use the `.CreateProperty` method with `.Properties.Append`

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The code now compiles fine, but when I run it I get an error on the line `db.Properties.Append oTxt` - **Object Required**.

Comment: It's running my end - when I included brackets around the `oTxt` variable it did error with 'Object Required'. Maybe try including brackets `.Append(oTxt)` to see if it solves the issue your end? Otherwise I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Access is Bazaar - `Call db.Properties.Append(oTxt)` works, but `db.Properties.Append oTxt` does not!  Thank you, that does indeed do what it says on the tin.  The only thing I have to do now is bring the already open instance of notepad to the front when the user clicks the help button, but that's another question!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it.  Here is a function to see if notepad is running.

Declare these up top.

```
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumProcesses Lib "PSAPI.DLL" ( _
    lpidProcess As Long, ByVal cb As Long, cbNeeded As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumProcessModules Lib "PSAPI.DLL" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, lphModule As Long, ByVal cb As Long, lpcbNeeded As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetModuleBaseName Lib "PSAPI.DLL" Alias "GetModuleBaseNameA" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = &H10
Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
```

Then send this the process name. `b = IsProcessRunning("notepad.exe")`

```
Private Function IsProcessRunning(ByVal sProcess As String) As Boolean
'Check to see if a process is currently running
Const MAX_PATH      As Long = 260
Dim lProcesses()    As Long
Dim lModules()      As Long
Dim N               As Long
Dim lRet            As Long
Dim hProcess        As Long
Dim sName           As String

sProcess = UCase$(sProcess)
ReDim lProcesses(1023) As Long

If EnumProcesses(lProcesses(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
    For N = 0 To (lRet \ 4) - 1
        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, lProcesses(N))
        If hProcess Then
            ReDim lModules(1023)
            If EnumProcessModules(hProcess, lModules(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
                sName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar)
                GetModuleBaseName hProcess, lModules(0), sName, MAX_PATH
                sName = Left$(sName, InStr(sName, vbNullChar) - 1)
                If sProcess = UCase$(sName) Then
                    IsProcessRunning = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
        CloseHandle hProcess
    Next N
End If
End Function
```